# Transactions with Vapor 4/Fluent

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to save 2 related models and would like to use a database transaction for this so that in case of a failure nothing is written to the database.

In Vapor 3 you could use the following:

```
req.transaction(on: .<#dbid#>) { conn in
    // use conn as your connection
}
```

How can this be done in Vapor 4? Unfortunately, the documentation for transactions doesn't exist for version 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `req.db.transaction` to create a new transaction for use. The tests are the best place to look to find examples - e.g. [here](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-kit/blob/0b6303c40170896ff53981deb61bd5a63c9e71fd/Sources/FluentBenchmark/Tests/TransactionTests.swift#L11)

(Also an issue on GH at vapor/docs would be great to ensure the docs get written!)

Comment: This is the right solution, I've also filed an issue on GitHub for adding the documentation.